# Do I receive dividend if my stocks are assigned on ex-dividend date?

Tags: options, dividends, ex-dividend-date

I owned a stock and sold a call option on it.
On the Ex-dividend date the option was assigned at pre-market hours and stocks were sold at pre-market.
Am I still entitled to receive dividends because I owned the stock up to ex-dividend date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received notification on the morning of the ex-dividend date.  However, the option was exercised the day before ex-div so you are not entitled to the dividend.